# taking the trace

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, trace

could anyone show me the first couple of steps in taking the trace of something like this, im not sure how to start.

'Tr[$\gamma($$\gamma k + $$\gamma p + $$\gamma q + m) $$\gamma ($$\gamma k + $$\gamma p+ $m)]'

Comment: A good first step would be to define what you have written down. Are you taking the trace of a matrix, the trace of an operator, ... ?

Comment: taking the trace of matrices.

Comment: what is the matrix $\gamma$? I have only seen expressions like these where $\gamma$ had a vector index. Typically then $k$ $p$ and $q$ also have vector indices which are contracted with the index from the $\gamma$. Also $k$ is being integrated over and we can get some mileage out of that fact. Is that the case here?

Comment: the gamma matrices are the 4-tuple of dirac gamma matrices. the trace of the expression is supposed to be representative of the numerator of the propagator of two fermions in a Feynman diagram. and the gamma matrices followed by either a k, p or q are supposed to be equivalent to Feynman's slashe notation commonly used in fermion propagators.

Comment: Would like to mention that once you understand *how* it works, it is straightforward to make a computer algebra system (CAS) like Mathematica or more hep-th specific [Cadabra](http://cadabra.phi-sci.com/index.html) do these tedious & mechanical manipulations for you. Just look at some of the Cadabra samples to get a gist of it. Though like any CAS use case I don't recommend you blindly trust the system: make sure you understand how it's working first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the indices on the gamma matrices. So your expression is actually 
\begin{align}
\text{tr}[\gamma^\mu(\gamma^\alpha k_\alpha + \gamma^\beta p_\beta + \gamma^\delta q_\delta + m) \gamma_\mu(\gamma^\rho k_\rho + \gamma^\sigma p_\sigma + m) ].
\end{align}

Then you use the [trace technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Trace_identities) to evaluate the traces. For example, the $m^2$ term has the coefficient 16 because $\text{tr}[\gamma^\mu \gamma_\mu m^2] = 16 m^2$.

The $k^2$ term has $\text{tr}[\gamma^\mu\gamma^\alpha \gamma_\mu \gamma^\rho]k_\alpha k_\rho = 4(g^{\mu \alpha}\delta_\mu^\rho - g^\mu{}_\mu g^{\alpha \rho} + g^{\mu \rho}\delta^\alpha{}_\mu) k_\alpha k_\rho = 4(k^2 - 4k^2 + k^2) = -8k^2$,

and so on.